# Codecademy flipboard code not working on my computer

Tags: javascript, html, css, flipboard

I went through the Codecademy flipboard tutorial which basically just shows you how to put a .js file together for a carousel.  I took the code from the website and created files on my computer.

I'm saving them as separate files on my computer in one folder.  I've tried both pointing the file to a js file I downloaded from the js website (that I placed in the same folder) AND I tried using the website Codecademy provided as the source so I don't think that's the issue.  I have each of the files saved separately as app.js, index.html, and style.css.

When I run it, it looks as it should but the the carousel isn't working.  However, if I run it on Codecademy it runs perfectly.  What gives?  I'm just trying to understand the carousel fully and the interaction between .js .html and .css  I'm also trying to build my own resume type website with a carousel but I can't do that until I fully understand each of these parts.  Something Codecademy fails to do in my eyes.

## app.js

```js
    var main = function() {
      $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
      });

      $('.arrow-next').click(function() {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var nextDot = currentDot.next();

        if (nextSlide.length === 0) {
          nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
          nextDot = $('.dot').first();
        }

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
      });

      $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

        if (prevSlide.length === 0) {
          prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
          prevDot = $('.dot').last();
        }

        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
      });
    }


    $(document).ready(main);
```

## index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="logo-icon">
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/logo.png">
      </a>

      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Get the App</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Magazines</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Web Tools</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">More <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Community</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Maps Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Eng Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Advertisers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Publishers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider">

    <div class="slide active-slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
            <h1>Flipboard Is Your Personal Magazine</h1>
            <p>It's a single place to discover, collect and share the news you care about. Add your favorite social networks, publications and blogs to stay connected to the topics and people closest to you.</p>

            <ul class="get-app">
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ios.png">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/android.png">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/windows.png">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/blackberry.png">
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/home.png" width="540px">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide slide-feature">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/cnn.png">
            </a>
            <a href="#">Read Now</a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
            <h1>Enjoy Flipboard Magazines</h1>
            <h2>on the Web</h2>
            <p>Millions of people use Flipboard to read and collect the news they care about, curating their favorite stories into their own magazines on any topic imaginable. Now magazines created by our readers, from Dali to End Trafficking, can be shared
              and enjoyed on the Web by anyone, anywhere.</p>

          </div>
          <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/magazines.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
            <h1>Badges & Widgets</h1>
            <p>Millions of people use Flipboard to read and collect the news they care about, curating their favorite stories into their own magazines. Now you can promote the ones you create or think are awesome.</p>

            <ul class="get-app">
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ios.png">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/android.png">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/windows.png">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/blackberry.png">
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/bw.png" width="540px">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="slider-nav">
    <a href="#" class="arrow-prev">
      <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-prev.png">
    </a>
    <ul class="slider-dots">
      <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
      <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="arrow-next">
      <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-next.png">
    </a>
  </div>

  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

## style.css

```css
/* General */

.container {
  width: 960px;
}


/* Header */

.header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;

  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;

  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 15px;
}


/* Menu */ 

.header .menu {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.menu > li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #898989;
}

/* Dropdown */

.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  min-width: 105px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #898989;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


/* Carousel */

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 470px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.slide {
  background: transparent url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/feature-gradient-transparent.png') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.active-slide {
    display: block;
}

.slide-copy h1 {
  color: #363636;  

  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;

  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 105px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.slide-copy h2 {
  color: #b7b7b7;

  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;

  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.slide-copy p {
  color: #959595;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.slide-img {
  text-align: right;
}

/* Slide feature */

.slide-feature {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ac.png');
  height: 470px;
}

.slide-feature img {
  margin-top: 112px;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.slide-feature a {
  display: block;
  color: #6fc5e0;

  font-family: "HelveticaNeueMdCn", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;

  font-size: 20px;
}

.slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.arrow-prev {
  margin-right: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.arrow-next {
  margin-left: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.slider-dots {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.slider-dots li {
  color: #bbbcbc;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.slider-dots li.active-dot {
  color: #363636;
}

/* App links */

.get-app {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 9px;
}

.get-app li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.get-app img {
  height: 40px;
}
```

Snippet:

```js
var main = function() {
      $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
      });

      $('.arrow-next').click(function() {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var nextDot = currentDot.next();

        if (nextSlide.length === 0) {
          nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
          nextDot = $('.dot').first();
        }

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
      });

      $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

        if (prevSlide.length === 0) {
          prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
          prevDot = $('.dot').last();
        }

        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
      });
    }


    $(document).ready(main);
```

```css
/* General */

.container {
  width: 960px;
}


/* Header */

.header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 15px;
}


/* Menu */ 

.header .menu {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.menu > li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #898989;
}

/* Dropdown */

.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  min-width: 105px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #898989;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


/* Carousel */

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 470px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.slide {
  background: transparent url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/feature-gradient-transparent.png') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.active-slide {
    display: block;
}

.slide-copy h1 {
  color: #363636;  
  
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 105px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.slide-copy h2 {
  color: #b7b7b7;
  
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.slide-copy p {
  color: #959595;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.slide-img {
  text-align: right;
}

/* Slide feature */

.slide-feature {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ac.png');
  height: 470px;
}

.slide-feature img {
  margin-top: 112px;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.slide-feature a {
  display: block;
  color: #6fc5e0;
  
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueMdCn", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  
  font-size: 20px;
}

.slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.arrow-prev {
  margin-right: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.arrow-next {
  margin-left: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.slider-dots {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.slider-dots li {
  color: #bbbcbc;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.slider-dots li.active-dot {
  color: #363636;
}

/* App links */

.get-app {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 9px;
}

.get-app li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.get-app img {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="logo-icon">
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/logo.png">
      </a>

      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Get the App</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Magazines</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Web Tools</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">More <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Community</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Maps Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Eng Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Advertisers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Publishers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider">

    <div class="slide active-slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
            <h1>Flipboard Is Your Personal Magazine</h1>
            <p>It's a single place to discover, collect and share the news you care about. Add your favorite social networks, publications and blogs to stay connected to the topics and people closest to you.</p>

            <ul class="get-app">
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ios.png">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/android.png">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/windows.png">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/blackberry.png">
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/home.png" width="540px">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide slide-feature">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/cnn.png">
            </a>
            <a href="#">Read Now</a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
            <h1>Enjoy Flipboard Magazines</h1>
            <h2>on the Web</h2>
            <p>Millions of people use Flipboard to read and collect the news they care about, curating their favorite stories into their own magazines on any topic imaginable. Now magazines created by our readers, from Dali to End Trafficking, can be shared
              and enjoyed on the Web by anyone, anywhere.</p>

          </div>
          <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/magazines.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
            <h1>Badges & Widgets</h1>
            <p>Millions of people use Flipboard to read and collect the news they care about, curating their favorite stories into their own magazines. Now you can promote the ones you create or think are awesome.</p>

            <ul class="get-app">
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ios.png">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/android.png">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/windows.png">
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/blackberry.png">
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/bw.png" width="540px">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="slider-nav">
    <a href="#" class="arrow-prev">
      <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-prev.png">
    </a>
    <ul class="slider-dots">
      <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
      <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="arrow-next">
      <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-next.png">
    </a>
  </div>

  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the file `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` in the same folder as your shown files?

Comment: so you have an index.html, app.js and style.css. you have included the style.css, jquery.min.js and app.js inside the index.html. Now the way you have done the code snippet is all wrong.

Comment: Have a look at your browser's Network panel to see if everything is loaded OK. Also, do you get any JavaScript errors? (+1 for a well formatted question featuring what you have tried).

Comment: @Sai, if you are of the view that someone has done something "all wrong", it is helpful (and customary) to explain why you think that.

Comment: @halfer- I am trying to create a proper fiddle of the code provided as we speak and trying to make sense of the question and where the OP may have gone wrong myself. I know the OP is new to site so i dont blame that person. No disrespect meant to OP

Comment: Here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/xt6vbt9q/ . I think i added all external resources (not sure)

Comment: @halex Yes, it's in the same folder as the other files.

Comment: @Sai, one of your`<li>`has the class `dropdown`, but this class does not exist, where is it defined? For me the Menu does not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things missing in your code.
Adding this:

```
currentSlide.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active-slide');
nextSlide.fadeIn(500).addClass('active-slide');
```

below your if statement in your click event handler for arrow-next will do the trick.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6nbo8htt/